# Where is the RAM on a Lenovo yoga tab 3

Tags: memory, tablet

Made the mistake of buying a Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 10" with only 1GB of memory. It's very slow and too late to return. I also have a Lenovo Yoga Tab 2 8" that was very responsive until its screen died this week. I'd love to remove its 2GB RAM and put it in the Tab 3. Is that possible without soldering?

I opened the Tab 2 but can't locate the RAM and my Google searches have been unsuccessful.

Comment: If you cannot find it then the RAM is probably soldered to the motherboard and is not replaceable.

Comment: There's a picture of the RAM chip towards the end of this http://www.myfixguide.com/manual/lenovo-yoga-tablet-2-disassembly/ As you can see, it's soldered to the main board. There's no guarantee it's compatible with the Tab 3. If it is, you'll need good soldering skills.